# optim() to get the observed information matrix

Tags: r

am trying to optimise penalised log-likelihood function using optim() function in r by using simulated data set , for logistic model, when i run the code its return an error that the object mypdf not found .
the code is
as follow:

```
library(simstudy)
d1 <- defData(varname = "x1", formula = 0.35, dist = "binary")
d1 <- defData(d1, varname = "x2", formula = 0.5, dist = "binary")
d1 <- defData(d1, varname = "x3", formula = 0.3, dist = "binary")

d1 <- defData(d1,varname = "y", formula = "-2 + 0.5*x1 + 0.5*x2 + 1*x3", 
dist = "binary", link = "logit")

dd <- genData(100, d1)

x.tilde<-as.matrix(x)

wrapper = function(args){
mypdf(x.tilde=arg[1],
    y=arg[2], 
    beta=arg[3])

myfnc<- y*log(exp(x.tilde %*% beta))/(1+exp(x.tilde %*% beta))+
(1-y)*log(1-(exp(x.tilde %*% beta)/(1+exp(x.tilde %*% beta))))

prior<- (beta/2)-log(1+exp(beta))

fnc<- myfnc+prior

return(fnc)
}


 par<- c(0.3, 0.25, 1, 0.521)

 fit2 <-optim (par=par,fn=mypdf ,hessian=TRUE)

info.mat<- -(fit2$hessian)

info.mat <- as.matrix(info.mat)
print(info.mat)


Error in (function (par)  : object 'mypdf' not found



any help?
```

Comment: you did not define any function mypdf

Comment: yes                             wrapper = function(args){
                                  mypdf(x.tilde=arg[1],
                                   y=arg[2], 
                                     beta=arg[3])

Comment: that does not define `mypdf()`.  It defines `wrapper()`